# Can't create new stage with multiple AnchorPanes

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on this simple application and trying to create a new stage/window when clicking on a button. I get this work when using a simple fxml-document with only one `AnchorPane`. In the scene I want to pop-up, there is a `TabPane` with two tabs. I've imported one fxml-document into each tab, and when I do that a new `AnchorPane` is created in each tab. So when I click the button in main scene nothing is happening. I really don't know how to solve this, does anybody have any ideas?

This is the code I'm using right now to show a new stage.

```
@FXML
private void showAddStage(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Add.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to set the size of the scene? And you should probably set the owner window (`initOwner(<parent-stage>)`).

Comment: Do you see the new window at all? If no try adding a `println` statement to `showAddStage` for debugging to make sure that it is being called.

Comment: Does the method get invoked? Are there any error messages? You should put something in the catch block, even if it's just e.printStackTrace()